# Returning the existence of a key in a dict by searching key substring

Tags: c#

I have a dictionary of string people (key) and string addresses (value). I want to have an if statement that returns true if any key in my dictionary contains the substring 'anders'. Is there any way to do this? I have tried dict.ContainsKey("anders") but that just returns true if any key is explicitly named 'anders'. I would like it to return true even if the key is anderson or andersen. I know this is a pretty strange case but i need it for a purpose.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "wildcard search" for dictionary keys. In order to do this type of search, you are going to lose the O(constant) search that a dictionary gives you.

You'll have to iterate over the keys of the dictionary and look for those that contain the substring you require. Note that this will be an O(n*X) iteration, where n is the number of keys and X is the average size of your key string.

There's a nifty one-liner that will help:

```
bool containsKey = myDictionary.Keys.Any(x => x.Contains("mySubString"));
```

But it's a heavy operation.

Answer (score 6):

You'll have to iterate over the collection and check each one. The LINQ `Any` method makes this fairly simple:

```
dict.Keys.Any(k => k.Contains("anders"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Everyone has already pointed out the obvious (and correct) `Any` method, but one note: Using `String.Contains` as the predicate will only return true if the case of the substring is also correct. To do a case-insensitive search, use a simple Regex:

```
dict.Keys.Any(x => Regex.IsMatch(x, "(?i)anders"));
```

Or use IndexOf with the StringComparison argument (as in [Case insensitive 'Contains(string)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring)):

```
dict.Keys.Any(x => x.IndexOf("anders", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);
```

Comment: @M.Babcock I had already updated my answer when I saw your comment :)

Comment: The string comparison is less important than the iteration, in my opinion, but you make an excellent point.

Answer (score 1):

```
var pair = dict.FirstOrDefault(kvp => kvp.Key.Contains("anders"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(dict.Keys.Any(k=>k.Contains("anders")))
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the keys of the dictionary and check each if it contains the string:

```
bool found = false;
foreach (string key in dict.Keys)
{
    if (key.Contains("anders"))
    {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

or using LINQ:

```
bool found = dict.Keys.Any(key => key.Contains("anders"));
```